# Error: Timeout trying to fetch resolutions from npm

Tags: npm, package.json

When I try to run my npm `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` command I this error:

`Error: Timeout trying to fetch resolutions from npm`

Why is this suddenly happening and how to fix this issue?